# Java data format is not working in all scenarios

Tags: java, validation, simpledateformat, date-parsing

What is the mistake I did in my below code? If we do not pass date format like **yyyy-MM-dd**, it should throw parse error and it should return false but below one scenario not working

- 2020-08-19-->This is working fine and returning true
- 2020-19-08-->This is working fine and returning false
- 20-08-19-->This should return false. It is not working and returning true

I am not understanding why third scenario getting failed.

Clarification: I am asking: if we pass input: `20-19-08`, it should return false, right? But its returning true. My problem is, if I pass 20 instead of 2020, it should return false.

### Code

```
    public static boolean validateDateFormat(String strDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfrmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        sdfrmt.setLenient(false);
        try {
            sdfrmt.parse(strDate);
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Print the date after you've parsed it, and see what it is.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Hi AbhiRam. I wonder if I could trouble you to not add begging messages to your questions? Stack Overflow is intended to be a useful resource of Q&A for future developers, and thus a technical writing style is preferred. Pleading doesn't generally work on volunteers anyway - stick to a neutral tone if you can.

Answer (score 2):

20-19-08 does not follow the format because the year is not specified as a four digit number (though the formatter you are using will recognize both 20 and 2020 as valid years, just not the same year) and your month value according to the format string will come up as 19, which is not valid.

Comment: if i pass 20-19-08 it should throw parse error right but its not throwing

Comment: Your format pattern is wrong. MM stands for month, and there aren't 19 months in a year.

Comment: if we are not pass year as 4 digits it should throw parse error but its not throwing thats what is my problem

Comment: The format pattern is the same as before the edit. That is your problem, regardless of any other error you may or may not be seeing. As proof, the code in the other answer works and it is functionally equivalent to yours except for the format string, which is different. Also your code catches the error but only returns false, and throws nothing.

Comment: I can’t see how this answer might answer the question asked? I tend to take what the answer says as reasons why one might expect an exception, but still none is thrown (nor caught).

Comment: Well, the question itself is not consistent (read the clarification and see how it uses a different date format input than the rest of the question). In the clarification, the issue is the incorrect input and the behaviour it produces is different than the one described in the rest of the question. As for the rest of the question, another answer shows how both input formats originally used work, so that's just how the API is designed to work.

Comment: The edit changes nothing with regards to my answer. The input provided in the clarification still has 19 in the position that the parser will interpret as the month. I have, however, edited my answer to include in it the main point that I made later on in a comment and that is causing the second test case (which originally appeared in the clarification, before you edited the question) to fail. And a further point I originally didn't make about the parser being designed by default to recognize both 20 and 2020 as valid years despite the format being "yyyy".

Answer (score 1):

You are not throwing the exception in catch block. hence it does not throw anything simply retyurn false. To get the actual exception throw it or printStackTrace() it.

This approach should be working for both conditions :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String ss = "20-19-08";
        if(validateDateFormat(ss)){
            System.out.println("SUCCESS");
        }else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }
        
    }
    
    public static boolean validateDateFormat(String strDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdfrmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-dd-MM");
        sdfrmt.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date date = sdfrmt.parse(strDate);
            System.out.println("Formatted Date :: "+date);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Test results :

```
Input : 20-19-08
Output : 

Formatted Date :: Mon Aug 19 00:00:00 UTC 20
SUCCESS

Input : 2020-19-08
Output :

Formatted Date :: Wed Aug 19 00:00:00 UTC 2020
SUCCESS
```

Comment: @AbhiRam It will not throw any ERROR because you are not using "throw" exception in your code. You are just catching the exception and returning false from there. To throw any exception add the code for throwing the exception.

Comment: i am asking if we pass Input : 20-19-08 it should return false right but its returning true

Comment: @AbhiRam You told your second scenario is failing. I could not reproduce the failing scenario that you see. Please show some exact test cases output ti System.out.println() statements. Also for your doubt it will parse the 20  and 2020 both

Comment: My problem is if are pass 20 instead of 2020 it should return false

Comment: Hope your understand what i am saying

Comment: Thanks, JavaHelper, for trying to contribute. The question is quite clear from the comments: why is the method returning true when given the string `20-08-19`? As far as I can see, your answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @OleV.V.: Initially the question was not very clear, now after edit it is clear. I thought his code was failing for 20-08-19 but now I got his main doubt. He is using `SimpleDateFormat`  which can give weird result like this.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

I don’t think `SimpleDateFormat` is able to give you the validation you are asking for. Which is just the same since that class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. You shouldn’t use it anyway. I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for all of your date work. And it validates your date string nicely. Use `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.

```
public static boolean validateDateFormat(String strDate) {
    try {
        DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE.parse(strDate);
    }
    catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Try it out:

```
    String candidate = "20-08-19";
    boolean valid = validateDateFormat(candidate);
    System.out.format("Is %s valid? %s%n", candidate, valid);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Is 20-08-19 valid? false
> ```

We can try some other strings too:

> ```
> Is 2020-13-19 valid? false
> Is 2020-08-19 and some more text that should not be here valid? false
> ```

And a valid one:

> ```
> Is 2020-08-19 valid? true
> ```

### Why didn’t your code work?

> i am not understanding why second scenario getting failed can some one
> help me please

This is the way `SimpleDateFormat` parses numbers. From the documentation:

> - **Year**: If the formatter's `Calendar` is the Gregorian calendar, the following rules are applied.
>
>   - …
>   - For parsing, if the number of pattern letters is more than 2, the year is interpreted literally, regardless of the number of digits.
>     So using the pattern "MM/dd/yyyy", "01/11/12" parses to Jan 11, 12
>     A.D.
>   - …

I think the example matches your situation pretty nicely. Even though you use `yyyy` in the format pattern string, `SimpleDateFormat` is happy to parse `20` as year 20 AD. This would explain why no exception is thrown, which in turn causes your method to return true.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Comment: yes nice and correct explanation. I give an upvote for this.