# SimpleDateFormat is accepting date format which is not mentioned

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
String dateString = "2022-02-1";
boolean status = false;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
dateFormat.setLenient(false);
try {
    dateFormat.parse(dateString);
    status = true;
} catch (Exception e) {
    status = false;
}
System.out.println(status);
```

Here `yyyy-MM-dd` is the given format so I'm assuming it accepts only '2022-02-01' but it's accepting '2022-02-1' also. How can I make it accept only '2022-02-01' and return false for '2022-02-1'?

Comment: You can’t. Fortunately you shouldn’t try either. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `LocalDate.parse("2022-02-01")` works whereas `LocalDate.parse("2022-02-1")` throws an exception just like you wanted.

Comment: Maybe similar: [Java data format is not working in all scenarios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526858/java-data-format-is-not-working-in-all-scenarios)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to *javadoc* for class [java.text.SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

> For parsing, the number of pattern letters is ignored unless it's needed to separate two adjacent fields.

In other words, `SimpleDateFormat` treats `dd` the same as `d` when parsing a string.

Since Java 8, you should be using [date-time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

```java
String dateString = "2022-02-1";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(formatter.parse(dateString));
```

Running above code throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-02-1' could not be parsed at index 8
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:1949)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1777)
```

Comment: No need for your `DateTimeFormatter`. The standard ISO 8601 format of YYYY-MM-DD is handled by default in `LocalDate.parse`.

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71597307/642706) is correct. But to more directly address a solution, trap for `DateTimeParseException` to detect faulty input.

No need to specify a formatting pattern in your case. Your expected input format complies with ISO 8601 standard. Those standard formats are used by default in *java.time* when parsing/generating text.

```
try {
    LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
    … handle valid input
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    … handle faulty input
}
```