# Date format issue 'dd.MM.yyyy'

Tags: java, validation, simpledateformat

```
private boolean isValidDateString(String value){  // value = "01.02.22"
    if(value != null){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
        try{
            Date parse = sdf.parse((String) value);
        }catch (Exception e){
            LOG.debug("Invalid date string : "+value);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here it returning `true` for value `"01.01.22"`. I have to show error message like "format should be 'dd.MM.yyyy'", so I need the method to return `false` for such a string. How do I obtain that?

Comment: If it's returning true, why should you show an error message?

Comment: it should accept only "dd.MM.yyyy" format

Comment: I think you probably expect your date to not be parsed because "22" is not a year with a length of 4. You should however know that "22" parsed as "yyyy" will simply refer to the year 22, not 2022. No error will be thrown.

Comment: make sure to use `sdf.setLenient(false);` if not you won't get exception for invalid date like `32.01.22`

Comment: @Anothercoder Even with lenient set to false 22 will still be parsed as a valid "yyyy" year. So while it may be a good idea to set it to true it won't solve OPs issue. He'll probably have to do some secondary validation either on the string before parsing or the date after parsing.

Comment: Please stop using these obsolete Java classes such as SimpleDateFormat and Date. They are known to have serious usability issues, and for the past 8 years (since Java 8) have been replaced by the `java.time` classes. Use `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(value)`. This will also do what you want it to do, i.e. ensure you have a 4-digit year.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SimpleDateFormat is accepting date format which is not mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71597191/simpledateformat-is-accepting-date-format-which-is-not-mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your method, changed to use the more recent `java.time.format` package. This will reject "01.01.22", just as you want it to, as it requires a 4-digit year.

All new code should be using `java.time.*` and stop using `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`.

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeParseException;

private final var formatDDMMYYYY = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

private boolean isValidDateString(String value){  // value = "01.02.22" or null
    if (value != null) {
        try {
            formatDDMMYYYY.parse(value);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            LOG.debug("Invalid date string", e);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```